How to secure my home network when using Cloudflare tunnel to a VM in Hyper-V?
I am running a website on Apache server in Ubuntu Server 22.04.
The Ubuntu Server is a guest VM in Hyper-V.
In order to connect to the website from the outside world, I am using Cloudflare Tunnel with the IP of the VM.
Currently, I have a static IP in the Ubuntu Server different than the IP range of the home network.
I did it by doing the following:

I created an Internal Network Adapter using Hyper-V manager
I set a different IP Range for the Virtual Network - 172.15.100.x (Subnet mask 255.255.255.0), while the home network is 192.168.2.x.
I added the newly created adapter to the Guest alongside the original adapter (so currently 2 adapters connected to the VM)
I set a static IP to my Ubuntu Server - 172.15.100.2

Is this considered a VLAN? Is this secured enough? Or there are steps I need to do or completely configure it differently to make it "separate" from my home network in case the web server is compromised?


Is this considered a VLAN?

In a general sense, yes; it provides the same isolation that a VLAN would. (In fact, it provides even more isolation than that – each Hyper-V network is like a fully separate Ethernet switch that has its own VLANs.)
Technically the 1:1 equivalent of VLANs that people discuss would be the "VLAN ID" field in your VM settings (multiple IDs coexisting on the same "wire"), but in general speech any kind of isolated network is often called a "VLAN", and creating a separate Hyper-V network still meets the goal of isolation.

Is this secured enough?

If your description is complete, then this configuration has absolutely no effect, because the VM in question is still connected to the original network, meaning there is zero actual isolation that VLAN usage is meant to provide (and the new network you've created isn't used for anything at all).
In a secure configuration, hosts would only be in a single network or VLAN at a time, and the only devices that would straddle multiple VLANs would be the routers that act as gateways from one network to another; the security comes from the router being the only path between hosts and therefore being able to enforce firewall rules.
In theory Windows might be capable of that – after all, in the setup that WSL uses by default, the WSL VM is on a separate network and the host OS is the router between the two – but I'm really not sure what filtering capabilities Windows has as a router (the "Windows Firewall" doesn't seem to deal with routed traffic at all). If there's a feature, it's hidden somewhere.
So I'd rather use a separate router, e.g. I have a small hardware Mikrotik router, some people use a second VM running Opnsense or a regular Linux with iptables – instead of your webapp VM being on both networks, you'd use this configuration for the "gateway" VM only, meanwhile the webapp server would be only connected to the "internal" network and would be forced to go through the Opnsense system's firewall rules.
And, of course, the important part is that you have to create those firewall rules. Networks and subnets are isolated only as far as the rules specify; e.g. if you want the Ubuntu VM to have no access to your main LAN subnet, that's something you must manually specify in the rules that you set up. (It's not much though – the entire setup would be 2-4 rules total, I expect.)

Thank you! I do not have a spare router currently so I can only do a virtual solution like you suggested with pfSense (will OpenWrt work as well?). If I understood correctly, does this diagram I drew depicts how the network should look like: https://imgur.com/a/2gGMRft ? (Obviously a rough diagram )

Yes, although you only need two networks – the pfSense or OpenWrt VM can have its main interface directly connected to the 192.168.x.x network, without involving Hyper-V's own routing/NAT.
